# How to add an OnMouseClick listener to a selected item inside a JComboBox popup menu?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I am doing a desktop application where I need that when the user click or select an specific item (lest say "SHOW.DIALOG.ITEM") of a `JComboBox` triggers a listener that open a new `JDialog` that I use to configure that item. The code in 1 shows how I do it with a `ItemListener` and it works fine in showing the `JDialog`. In another part of the application where I load the values of the combo box (see code 2) I set to the `JComboBox` that the selected value is the specific item that shows the dialog and of curse it shows the dialog to the user because the combo box has the `ItemListener` and the if() condition,but the problem is that in my application I do not want that behavior to happen in that moment, i just want to happen only when the user select the item in the combo box. That is why I try to add an `OnClickMouse` listener instead of the `ItemListener` because I believe that may resolve my problem, but I can not find how to add a mouse listener to the `comboBox` that works like I want (I have try the `addMouseListener` with an `onClick` `MouseAdapter` but it do not work in showing the dialog). If anyone has a better idea of how I should do this or a way to adding an `OnMouseClick` listener to the `comboBox` that emulates the wanted behavior,it will be very helpful. Thanks

**1)** Adding item listener to the `comboBox` that shows the `dialog` after selecting the item

```
comboBox.addItemListener(e -> {
    if (ItemEvent.SELECTED == e.getStateChange()) {
        String valueAfterSelection = e.getItem().toString();
        if (valueAfterSelection.equalsIgnoreCase("SHOW.DIALOG.ITEM")) {
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**2)** Setting to the `comboBox` the specific item (this open the dialog and I do not want that to happen in that moment)

```
String value = reader.readComboBoxValue();
if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("SHOW.DIALOG.ITEM")) {
    comboBox.setSelectedItem(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always remove the listener before changing the selection:

```
comboBox.removeItemListener(...);
comboBox.setSelectedItem(value);
comboBox.addItemListener(...);
```

This means you would need to keep a reference to the listener when you create it, so you can easily remove/add as needed.